# passing value with protocol: ViewController to .xib file in swift

Tags: swift, protocols, xib, viewcontroller

So i have a class "CalendarioViewController" with one protocol "DateSelectedDelegate".

Protocol:

```
protocol DateSelectedDelegate {
func dateSelected (date: String)}
```

I declare a variable protocol type:

`var dateDelegate: DateSelectedDelegate? = nil`

Into my class "CalendarioViewController" i have a @IBAction button:

```
@IBAction func gotoHotelVC(_ sender: Any) {

    if dateDelegate != nil {

        if fechaSelected.text != nil {

            let data = fechaSelected.text
            dateDelegate?.dateSelected(date: data!)
        }   
    } 
}
```

In my secondVC or "FechasViewController" i use the protocol define early, i call the CalendarioViewController with two button. The FechasViewController is a xib file:

```
@IBAction func fechaArribo(_ sender: Any) {

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc:CalendarioViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "calendario") as! CalendarioViewController
    vc.dateDelegate = self
    self.window!.rootViewController = vc

}

@IBAction func fechaSalida(_ sender: Any) {

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc:CalendarioViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "calendario") as! CalendarioViewController
    vc.dateDelegate = self
    self.window!.rootViewController = vc

}
```

my @IBOutlet:

```
 @IBOutlet weak var fechaArriboLabel: UILabel!
```

Use protocol:

`extension FechasViewController: DateSelectedDelegate {
    func dateSelected(date: String) {
        fechaArriboLabel.text = date
        print(date)
        print(fechaArriboLabel.text!)
    }
}`

> The line print(date) or print(fechaArriboLabel.text!) is work just fine... but my xib label don't not change anything:

here my xib:[image]

and this is my Storyboard:

[image]

Put here my entire code:
[image]

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9J65G.png)

[image]

Please...help!

Comment: Your `FechasViewController` is a sub-class of `CustomViewHandler`. And your `CustomViewHandler` is a `UIView` sub-class. So where is your `UIViewController`'s sub-class?

Comment: If your print statement is working then there might be problem with IBOutlet.

Comment: @Jignesh Agola :  what than problem will posible be? is right connected to the class. if i put this line of code: fechaArriboLabel.text = "HELLO" is work when i pressed the button. But when i back of my CalendarViewController to the ViewController or the xib file..he Is put in its original state, and that is the real problem here..i guess

Comment: @nayem : my sub-class UIViewController is not participe here. he is just load the xib file. I guess this is not problem...

Comment: Put a breakpoint inside `func dateSelected(date: String) {...}` of your implemented `extension FechasViewController: DateSelectedDelegate {...}` and see if execution stops there or not.

Comment: yeah...this also work...i think the problem is when load again the view (the xib file or ViewController: UIViewController